# Pandas - ¿Es posible una reasignación dinámica del parámetro usecols?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Dispongo de  una hoja Excel ([Ver aquí](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2unmplfd8lytmye/Fondos.xlsx?dl=0)) en la que dedico tres columnas a cada uno de  diversos fondos de inversión. La hoja tiene 45 columnas.

Con la sentencia:

```
df = pd.read_excel('Fondos.xlsx', 'Fondos', header = None, usecols=[0, 1, 2])
```

consigo enviar a un df el rango de columnas que deseo.
Ahora bien, para el programa sería deseable que el parámetro **usecols** fuera dinámico, es decir, que dependiendo del valor que quiero analizar, las columnas varíen en la asignación a **usecols**

¿Es posible conseguir que la asignación a **usecols**  cambie dependiendo de la selección del valor a analizar que elija en un menú para no tener que,  reescribir toda esa línea de código con cada posible opción?.
La primera opción probada ha sido crear la variable **cols** y asociarla a **usecols**. Esta opción funciona cuando se eligen las tres primeras columnas ([0, 1, 2]). En otros casos, por ejemplo ([9, 10, 11]), consigo un error que yo no se interpretar.

```
    runfile('E:/Python/Mi_Cartera_funciones/Calculos/importar_excel_3.py', wdir='E:/Python/Mi_Cartera_funciones/Calculos')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-10-2939cba4ea36>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('E:/Python/Mi_Cartera_funciones/Calculos/importar_excel_3.py', wdir='E:/Python/Mi_Cartera_funciones/Calculos')

  File "C:\Users\Media Service\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 710, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\Media Service\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 101, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "E:/Python/Mi_Cartera_funciones/Calculos/importar_excel_3.py", line 26, in <module>
    df1 = importar_excel(file, cols)

  File "E:/Python/Mi_Cartera_funciones/Calculos/importar_excel_3.py", line 16, in importar_excel
    df[0] = pd.to_datetime(df[0])

  File "C:\Users\Media Service\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 1964, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_column(key)

  File "C:\Users\Media Service\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 1971, in _getitem_column
    return self._get_item_cache(key)

  File "C:\Users\Media Service\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1645, in _get_item_cache
    values = self._data.get(item)

  File "C:\Users\Media Service\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 3590, in get
    loc = self.items.get_loc(item)

  File "C:\Users\Media Service\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2444, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))

  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 132, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc

  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 154, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc

  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 759, in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item

  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 765, in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item

KeyError: 0
```

Este es el script

```
 # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Thu Dec 21 16:05:50 2017
@author: efueyo
"""
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
#****************************************************************************
# Importar de Excel
def importar_excel(file, cols): 
    # Leer de un archivo Excel las columnas necesarias    
    df = pd.read_excel('Fondos.xlsx', 'Fondos', header = None, usecols=cols) 
    # Eliminar dos filas
    df = df.drop([0,1]) 
    # Reconocer fecha en la columna 0 
    df[0] = pd.to_datetime(df[0])
    # Renombrar columnas
    df.rename(columns = {0:"Fecha", 1:"Valor", 2:"Beneficio"}, inplace = True)
    # Ordenar por fechas
    df = df.sort_values(by = "Fecha", ascending = False)
    return df

file = "Fondos.xlsx"
cols = [9, 10, 11]

df1 = importar_excel(file, cols)

print (df1.head(4))
```

Comment: Seria algo como esto: `cols = [0, 1, 2]` `df = pd.read_excel('Fondos.xlsx', 'Fondos', header = None, usecols=cols)`? ¿a eso te refieres?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vamos por partes:

#### Error al importar el excel

Si revisas la salida del error:

```
File "E:/Python/Mi_Cartera_funciones/Calculos/importar_excel_3.py", line 16, in importar_excel
    df[0] = pd.to_datetime(df[0])
File "C:\Users\Media Service\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 1964, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_column(key)
```

Veras que la última línea ejecutada en tu script antes del error es `pd.to_datetime(df[0])`, el problema que estás accediendo a un índice de columna que no tienes, al usar `usecols=[9,10,11]`, lo que ocurre es que efectivamente solo se leen esas columnas pero el índice de las tres segirá siendo 9, 10 y 11 respectivamente, por lo que en realidad deberías hacer es `pd.to_datetime(df[9])` y así con cada grupo de columnas.

Voy a reescribir un poco tu rutina:

```
def importar_excel(file, cols):                          
    # Leer de un archivo Excel las columnas necesarias    
    df = pd.read_excel(file, 'Fondos', header = None, usecols=cols, skiprows=2) 
    # Reconocer fecha en la columna 0 
    df[0] = pd.to_datetime(df[cols[0]])
    # Renombrar columnas
    df.rename(columns = {cols[0]:"Fecha", cols[1]:"Valor", cols[2]:"Beneficio"}, inplace = True)
    # Ordenar por fechas
    df = df.sort_values(by = "Fecha", ascending = False)
    return df
```

Por empezar usamos el parámetro `skiprows=2` al leer el archivo y evitamos tener que hacer un `drop` luego. Por último accedemos a cada columna del `dataframe` accediendo al índice real, si el grupo es `cols=[9, 10, 11]` al hacer `pd.to_datetime(df[cols[0]])` estamos accediendo a la columna cuyo índice es 9, lo mismo hacemos con `df.rename(columns = {cols[0]:"Fecha", cols[1]:"Valor", cols[2]:"Beneficio"}, inplace = True)`

También podríamos acceder a las columnas de otras formas:

```
df[df.columns[0]] = pd.to_datetime(df[df.columns[0]])
```

o bien:

```
df.ix[:,0] = pd.to_datetime(df.ix[:,0])
```

#### Selección dinámica de columnas

Por lo que comentas, todas las columnas de tu Excel se organizan en grupos de 3 columnas, comenzando desde la primer columna. Teniendo esto en mente podrías hacer algo así:

```
grupo = 4
cols = list(range(grupo*3-3,grupo*3))
print(cols)

> [9, 10, 11]
```

Es decir generamos la lista de columnas a seleccionar en función al grupo elegido.

Comment: Efectivamente, la opción es muy buena e ingeniosa para elegir el grupo de columnas.

Comment: @efueyo,Son dos temas distintos, la selección simplemente configura que columnas vas a recuperar, los datos que hay o no hay en esas columnas son los que te dan el error. Si pudieras compartir la planilla, se puede analizar dónde exactamente esta el problema. Saludos

Comment: Asimismo, tu observación de que el error pueda estar relacionado con la sentencia en la que cambio el formato de la columna 0, me ha hecho darme cuenta de que en los rangos restantes el formato no ha sido cambiado . Voy a hacer alguna prueba más y si continúa dándome el error, subiré la hoja.

Comment: He cambiado el formato de la columna 3 del grupo 2, utilizando la misma sentencia, y el error persiste. Este es el enlace a la hoja   https://www.dropbox.com/s/2unmplfd8lytmye/Fondos.xlsx?dl=0

Comment: @efueyo, revisa mi última edición, ahí encontré el problema, no son los datos sino el índice que usas para acceder a cada columna. Saludos